# Sorting a JSON Object after modification

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

I'm currently working on a project that displays a list of items based on a JSON object. I also want to be able to sort the object based upon both strings and integers within the items of the object.

Currently I've managed to get them to list as well as sort by string values and integers (used latitude as a test) - my sorting functionality is fine.

Here is my JSON code (for parks):

```
[
    {
        "name":"Greenhead Park",
        "latitude":53.648748,
        "longitude":-1.796985,
        "image":"Greenhead_Park.jpg"
    },
    {
        "name":"Shibden Park",
        "latitude":53.730610,
        "longitude":-1.838229,
        "image":"Shibden_Park.jpg"
    },
    {
        "name":"Beaumont Park",
        "latitude":53.625146,
        "longitude":-1.809171,
        "image":"Beaumont_Park.jpg"
    }
]
```

Now my problem is that I want to sort it by distance. As you can see the JSON file does not contain a 'distance' element in the items. Currently I am using Google Maps API - Geocode to calculate the distance between the users location and the parks location.

Within a for loop, I am adding the new distance element to each item:

```
parks[i]["distance"] = distance;
```

When I sort the items by distance, I am logging the JSON object in the console to make sure that the object being sorted definitely contains the new addition 'distance'. The console shows:

[image]

So it looks like the distance is adding to the object just fine. However, when I console.log(a.distance) it comes back as undefined

So my problem is, once I add a temporary element to each item in the JSON object (in this case 'distance'), when I try to reference it, it comes back as undefined - despite the fact that when I console.log the object, it is clearly defined.

Any ideas where I am going wrong guys? Any help is appreciated

EDIT: For those asking what the 'a' variable is, here is the function to sort my object

```
function sortParks(parks,sortMethod){
    parks.sort(function(a, b){

        console.log(parks);
        console.log(a.name);
        console.log(a.distance);
        if(sortMethod == "az") return (a.name > b.name) ? 1 : (a.name < b.name) ? -1 : 0;
        else if(sortMethod == "za") return (a.name < b.name) ? 1 : (a.name > b.name) ? -1 : 0;
        else if(sortMethod == "dc") return a.distance - b.distance;
        else if(sortMethod == "df") return b.distance - a.distance;
        else alert("There was an issue identifying the sort type");

    });
    return parks;

}
```

It is not 'a' that comes back as undefined, it is 'distance'. When i console.log(a.name) the names show fine, when I console.log(a.distance), it returns as undefined

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code that you used to add and log the distances and sort the array, otherwise we won't be able to help you with it.

Comment: We have no idea what `a` is without seeing your code

Comment: If `a` is undefined it means that `a` is not what you think it is...

Comment: I've added some more code, hope it helps identify the problem

Answer (score 1):

Here is a calculation in JS you can use without calling googles API:

```
var earthRadius = 6371000; // meters
var latRad1 = lat1.toRadians();
var latRad2 = lat2.toRadians();
var latDiffRad = (lat2-lat1).toRadians();
var lonDiffRad = (lon2-lon1).toRadians();

var halfChordLen = Math.sin(latDiffRad/2) * Math.sin(latDiffRad/2) + Math.cos(latRad1) * Math.cos(latRad2) * Math.sin(lonDiffRad/2) * Math.sin(lonDiffRad/2);

var cur = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(halfChordLen), Math.sqrt(1-halfChordLen));

var dist = earthRadius * cur;
```

Answer (score 0):

So your code looks like this?

```
for(var i = 0; i < parks.length; i++) {
  parks[i]["distance"] = calcDistance(parks[i].latitude, parks[i].longitude, user.latitude, user.longitude);
}
```

That works fine. Nothing's undefined there. Here is a more complete example.
https://jsfiddle.net/yhkzo95L/

Comment: Yeah it looks very similar but this isn't my issue. When I add the distance to the JSON object items (as can be seen in the image I provided), the distance shows for each item in the object. However, when I then pass the parks object through to the function sortParks and console.log the distance, I get undefined.
The console.log shows that distance is defined as 0.43. When i try to console.log() it, i get undefined. When i console.log() the name it comes through fine, but the distance is undefined. Surely it is something to do with the fact that name is hard coded in, whereas distance isnt?

Comment: There is no error in the code you posted so far. You have to actually give us code that demonstrates the error. i.e. some code we can run and test like the jsfiddle I posted.